# Creating New list in Sharepoint on specified Path

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I want to programatically create list on Sharepoint using Web Services.
I tried "Lists.AddList Method" but it would create list in current site only.

Is there any other way to create list? **(Using Web Services : C#)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create List on specified path

```
        Lists listService            = new Lists();
        listService.PreAuthenticate  = true;
        listService.Credentials      = new NetworkCredential(username,password,domain;
        String url                   = "http://YourServer/SiteName/"; // put your desired path here 
        listService.Url              = url @ + /_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

        XmlNode ndList               = listService.AddList(NewListName, "Description", 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create SPWeb object of the desired location and add list in it dynamically. See following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms425818.aspx

Comment: thanx Brij.

But i am looking for solution using Web Services. (not using Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this MSDN page, [Lists.AddList Method (Lists)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist.aspx)?

I think here you can find what you need.

Comment: thanx jaloplo.
But as mentioned in my post above.
List.AddList Method add list in current site.
But here i want to create list on my own site (taking input from user)

Comment: Well, though question was answered, you can call any sharepoint web service from any of their webs. For example, you have a site with this url: http://yoursite.com, and you have a sub sub site with the url: http://yoursite.com/web/subweb. To call lists web service for this web you can use: http://yoursite.com/web/subweb/_vti_bin/lists.asmx, and create any list you need.